# Data frames pandas python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
id  age sallary
1    16   500
2    21   1000
3    25   3000
4    30   6000
5    40   25000
```

and a list of ids that I would like to ignore [1,3,5]

how can I get a data frame that will contain all the remaining rows: 2,4.

Big thanks for every one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) and negate the result using `~`:

```
In [42]:

ignore_ids=[1,3,5]
df[~df.id.isin(ignore_ids)]
Out[42]:
   id  age  sallary
1   2   21     1000
3   4   30     6000
```